# Modelling multiple instances of camunda workflows

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I have the following scenario

I have to do create multiple instances(count determined by call to DB) of 5 different business processes which are modelled in separate workflows

For illustration naming them

1. Workflow 1
2. Workflow 2
3. Workflow 3
4. Workflow 4
5. Workflow 5

I will have to start multiple instances of the above workflows based on some data in the database

I will also need a parent workflow(to manage creating the above workflows) which will essentially do the below steps
Note: This workflow should never die, unless stopped externally. I want this workflow as a scheduler to create instances of other workflows. This workflow will be started when the container starts

Step1. Read data from the database using a REST API in a service task.

. The data from step1 will tell the following information

```
Workflow 1 -> create 5 instances 
Workflow 2 -> create 2 instances 
Workflow 3 -> create 1 instances 
Workflow 4 -> nothing yet to create
Workflow 5 -> nothing yet to create
```

Note: We have some thresholds set, which ensures not many PI are being created by this process

Step 2: I am trying to start these process instances using the java API of the RuntimeService in the next service task

```
    runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("workflow1");. * 5 times
    runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("workflow2");. * 2 times
    runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("workflow3");. * 1 time
```

Not starting workflow 4 and workflow 5 as there is no need in this iteration

I am calling this number of times based on the data in step2

I am expecting that all these process instances will be started async 
The purpose of this workflow is only to start the other workflows

Step 3 . After i have finished starting all the process instances for workflow1 to workflow5
I am doing some process cleanup and sending the flow back to Step 1

This keeps going in a loop and does the same steps again

I observed that the execution of the workflows(workflow1 to workflow5) are not triggering at all . until the main workflow is stopped

I have tried different mechanism but unsuccessful in achieving the use case

What is the best approach to model this? I am not sure what has to be done to achieve this.Can someone please help with the same?

I am using the spring boot camunda starter to do the same

I have attached the master workflow which has 3 service tasks

1. Get Data (explained earlier)
2. Schedule Workflow(Start child workflows)
3. Cleanup

[image: Master workflow attached below]

Comment: what if you add a message task on the loop from clean up to get data ?then you must send a message after all other workflows are finished , to repeat again

Comment: Thanks Inv3r53 . This will create so many instances of the master workflow.This will flood up the history table. i do not want to create so many instances even though it will complete immediately after it finishes its job.Do you think , there is any other way without creating many instances ?

Comment: I meant adding a message task on master work flow - so in this case there is only a single master instance , repeating the cycle - get , schedule , clean in a loop

Comment: Are you talking about send/receive message tasks or message events?Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Please avoid cross-posting, it's hard to follow the discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44992296/modelling-multiple-instances-of-camunda-workflows

Answer (score 0):

From the [answer to my question](https://forum.camunda.io/t/how-do-i-model-launching-multiple-child-workflows-and-co-ordinating-their-completion/5027) on the Camunda forum:

In BPMN, you can mark an activity as multi-instance, meaning that it is executed multiple times either based on static configuration or based on a dynamic condition or collection variable. See https://camunda.org/bpmn/reference/#activities-task (scroll to Multiple Instance) for an introduction on this and https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.7/reference/bpmn20/tasks/task-markers/#multiple-instance for the Camunda implementation reference. In Camunda modeler, the multi-instance marker can be toggled via the context menu of an activity.